# Unable to send email s using Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, smtp

I'm new on Laravel and I'm trying to configure mail. My .env file  is configurated as:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=SMTP
MAIL_HOST=vserv.******.***
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=admin@******.***
MAIL_PASSWORD=*********   <--- (9 chars lengh)
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
```

For my mail test I'm using tinker:

```
>php artisan tinker
>>> Mail::send('mails.contact',[], function($message) { $message->to('sergio@******.****')->subject('Testing email'); });
```

Before testing I flush the cache as:

```
>php artisan config:cache
Configuration cache cleared!
Configuration cached successfully!
```

Tinker return this error:

```
 Swift_TransportException with message 'Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "admin@******.***" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator CRAM-MD5 returned Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure 
" in ****/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:457
```

Server side, mail log has the error:

```
Mar 14 16:47:13 vserv plesk_saslauthd[21227]: failed mail authenticatication attempt for user 'admin@******.***' (password len=8)
```

**note:** the password I used in env is 9 chars but in error message is always 1 char less! If I type a wrong password 10chars length the error show (password len=9) and so on. Does it make sense?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: This error looks like your credentials are wrong. Does your password contain a `#` character by any chance? The dotenv library recently updated and it could be considering anything after that to be a comment (so surround the password with quotes)

Comment: YEESSS!! The psw contains "#" !!!!!  Lol!!!! I'm going to test a new psw!

Comment: THANKS!!! It works!!!  I owe you a beer!!! I was getting crazy!  Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates that your username or password is wrong. In this case there is a `#` character in the password string, which causes the rest of the password to be interpreted as a comment.

The solution is to quote the password:

```
MAIL_PASSWORD="my#secret"
```

If it used to work and doesn't anymore, it might be because Laravel 5.8 included an updated version of the [dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) library which changed the behavior:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/beware-in-env-files

Comment: Thanks Travis! You made my day :)